# Confusing obligations generated by `Program` tactic

Tags: coq

I'm quite new to coq proof assistant and am still finding my feet. 
I've encountered a case which I don't know how to deal with: I tried to use `Program Fixpoint` tactic to weaken the requirements on my code to later prove the needed properties afterwards as so called `Obligations`. While most of them were easy, there were two obligations generated goals of which had form `[a-quite-simplee-xpr] = [my-function-name]_obligation_3`, generally speaking the goals were refering to other obligations which were proved before. I tried unfolding and do substitutions but it didn't really help.
If there's no general solution for such problems I can send the proof script + the screenshot of the obligation to add some context.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

One thing that might be happening is that you have types which contain both "data" and "proof" (typically if you're trying to make refinement types with `sig`, or a custom inductive Type which contains proof terms), and that your functions require proofs of propositional equality, which is generally too strong for such dependent types.

Proof terms should be irrelevant: the simplest way out is to resolve that goal using an axiom from `ProofIrrelevance` (in the stdlib).

There are axiom-free ways, but I believe they require much more work/expertise.

Comment: I didn't use refinement types (the sig). The only thing I did is: I have a value `P` of type `T x` and it's passed to function which takes values of type `T y`. I know that `x = y`. But that property has to be proven explicitly, coq cannot automatically proof.